# Updating to .Net 4.7.1 Framework

Tags: asp.net, .net, msbuild

So I have a project that has been around since 2011 with intermittent additions for Libraries and additional projects within the Solution.  I am attempting to update it to 4.7.1 for all libraries and projects to which I have all the libraries and projects set to the 4.7.1 frameworks in Properties -> Application -> Target framework, however, I am getting warnings, debug errors, and a slew of other issues related to framework where:

1) when I try to debug it says "this error is because you are running a .NET Framework 3.5-based application in .NET Framework 4."

1b)  generates an error in debug mode (it is linked with the error message in 1)...

2) I search all web.config files and all are showing 4.7.1 and no other references to any of the old projects

3) I receive an error message for mscorlib to which I tried to scour stackoverflow and MSDN but none of the solutions are working (tried removing and adding dependencies/references, etc.) =

No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.

What are all the sections within project I should be looking for to find where the error is occurring?  I am trying to create a checklist of all the different potential areas that it could generate from and start checking them off my list one by one...

any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: References and BIN folder...  Alot of your DLLs could be for the older framework... (Backup FIRST) I would try deleting all the MS DLLs from your BIN folder (leave 3rd party ones), and adding them back one by one..Examine the DLL files too - for version information...  Tedious but this is usually the problem...  Start with a small project first

Comment: Thanks...I will try this weekend when I can spend a large amount of time on it and hopefully this will work

Comment: The error you get is because during the build there are references to both an mscorlib from 4.7.1 and 3.5. This can happen when you have libraries compiled for .NET 3.5 referenced from a .NET 4.7.1 application. I would examine the dependencies to 3rd party libraries to make sure they are not depending on 3.5.