# NuGet Solution Not recognizing Installed Packages

Tags: c#, vb.net, nuget, nuget-package

This is a Follow up to my original post ([Updating to .Net 4.7.1 Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859720/updating-to-net-4-7-1-framework)) where I am running into an issue post 4.7.1 migration that the packages in NuGet are not recognized for any Project but are for the Class Libraries ...

I was attempting to try to reinstall some of the References but when I removed them I cannot add them back for either Projects or Libraries

The Newtonsoft.Json is installed in all packages but only Libraries are at least recognized (cannot remove to add back though)

[image: NuGet Error]

When I try to delete and add or insert into a Project that technically isnt showing the installed package in the Solutions Manager the following error occurs (same result (to be expected) with Package Manager Console):

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' with respect to project '', targeting
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1'
>
> Gathering dependency information took 103.99 ms Attempting to resolve
>   dependencies for package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' with
>   DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
>
> Resolving dependency information took 0 ms Resolving actions to
>   install package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' Resolved actions to install
>   package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3'
>
> Found package 'Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3' in
>   'C:\Users\%userprofile%\Source\Workspaces\MyProject1\MyProject1\packages'.
>   Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' already exists in folder
>   'C:\Users\%userprofile%\Source\Workspaces\MyProject1\MyProject1\packages'
>
> Install failed. Rolling back... Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' does
>   not exist in project ' ' Executing nuget actions took 24.04 ms
>
> Failed to add reference to 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
>
> Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try deleting the packages in windows explorer from the project folder and re-install them? You can also try creating the project again with the right target framework, add the package and copy the files from them project to the new location. Make a backup before you do something you might regret later.

Comment: I manually deleted the files from the packages folder through path provided in output so it would not see that there was an existing point of reference, but it still won’t install packages

Comment: start a new project with everything prepared and installed and move your files over. don't move the config file or anything that might have references to your old libraries. So basically don't move everything all in one shot.

Comment: Understood. It’ll take some time as it’s a fairly large solution with multiple projects so will break it down over a weeks time ... Thank you for your help. Will do.

Comment: @MMcCarson,  It seems you include package folder in Source Control? If yes, please remove it from source control.